# what is the iOS api to get statistics on app usage?

Tags: ios, ios8, usage-statistics

Is there an API in iOS (including in ios8) that can be used to get the information about which app users are using and for how long everyday?

Comment: As per my knowledge and experience, GoogleAnalytics is the best API so far.

Comment: Google analytics only tells me how much my app is being used. The question is about how to get usage statistics for all apps on the phone. I want to give user a table with times of how long he she is using all the apps

Comment: Oh... Sorry. I got ur problem. For that, I suggest that store users session into your database which is on cloud, and than display table of user with session. For that u can store data on Parse.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These statistics are not available on iOS, as they are seen as an breach of the users privacy.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://www.adjust.com/ I'm using this website for get statistics on my app. 
Download the AdjustSDK and configure Adjust with your code. It's really easy and get statistics which are "Install","Session" and "Revenue".
Also you can add event whatever you want.

Comment: adjust.com only tells me how much my app is being used. The question is about how to get usage statistics for all apps on the phone. I want to give user a table with times of how long he she is using all the apps

Comment: I understood your question now, that is really different. I have no idea about that.